# Multiline text area in angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How do I wrap text and have support for multiple line, using angular material 2 and angular.

```
<md-input-container fxFlex="18" fxFlexOffset="1">
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="Comments" name="Comments" mdInput placeholder="Comments" ></textarea>
        <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
    </md-input-container>
```

Wrapping text mean, text should be appear multi line if content is longer than width.

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping text?

Comment: side note: you should use the `mat` prefix as the `md` prefix has been deprecated in the latest version of material. See also [change log - Deprecation of "md" prefix](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix)

Answer (score 10):

- Doesn't `textarea` elements have multi-line support? Did you mean setting the rows for the `textarea`? Just use the native `rows` attribute and set it to the value (as a number) of your choice.

  ```html
  <md-input-container fxFlex="18" fxFlexOffset="1">
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="Comments" name="Comments" mdInput placeholder="Comments" rows="3"></textarea>
      <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
  </md-input-container>
  ```
- As for wrapping the text, I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: ok I added rows but then the problem is it does not shows the begning line

Comment: This is the correct answer. Can SO please stop downvoting anwers!??

Answer (score 5):

Not the exact answer for the question but since this is the best match in google search,
to set rows for a textarea in angular apperantly we need to use`cdkTextareaAutosize, cdkAutosizeMinRows`attributes .

```html
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput placeholder="Your Message" formControlName="message" cdkTextareaAutosize
        cdkAutosizeMinRows="6"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Important Tip:

If converting an existing **`<input/>`** control to a **`<textarea>`** don't forget to add **`</textarea>`** to close it - otherwise the Angular compiler will give you some **very** misleading errors!

(You don't need to do the same for `input` as it's a self closing tag.)